# Formula to combine gender and language

Tags: formula

I am looking for a formula which will help me for mass-mailings and marketing-mailings and so on. The salutation depends on the gender and language of the contact. I know that I can do both with the CASE-Formula. but how do I combine those two?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish what you are looking for by using the following formula:

```
CASE( Gender__c , 
   "Male", CASE( Language__c , 
      "English", "Mister",
      "French", "Monsieur",
      "Spanish", "Señor",
      "German", "Herr",
      null),
   "Female", CASE( Language__c , 
      "English", "Miss",
      "French", "Madame",
      "Spanish", "Señora",
      "German", "Frau",
      null),
   null)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can still use the same formula that you have to handle Gender or Language separately..

only change will be to check for the combined values instead of individual ones.. something like

```
CASE( Gender & Language ,
'MaleEnglish' , 'First Option',
'MaleFrench' , 'Second Option',
'MaleSpanish' , 'Third Option',
....
)
```